# Stream analytics - degraded - no output

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

What could cause the stream analytics job to go into degraded status?
Following is the screenshot. I have checked each Input and Output - all it says is **Additional details are temporarily unavailable**

No output produced. In Azure portal checked the audit logs - nothing helpful there. How do we troubleshoot this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is no additional information in the logs, please open support ticket or send subscription id to askasa@microsoft.com